Could I, in theory, expend all my spell slots to explode?
Like, when I say explode, I mean nothing remains, not me, not the enemy, nothing. Think Vegeta's final explosion against Majin Buu, and then again vs Toppo. Like, if I have all my spell slots available and am at level 20, can I theoretically do that?

The practicality of this is like, if there is a large army approaching something that, if they reach it, would destroy the entire world, you could stop them from getting anywhere near it

Is there anything that makes you think this is possible? Rules you are confused about?

in some games such rules exist (The Dark Eye, 4/4.1, allowed certain casters to burn themselves out in one last stretch of casting spells)

I would say that this is your second "this sounds cool, can I do it" question in a short space of time. To avoid a similar negative reception it would be worth next time trying to find the closest rule and asking about that, rather than just presenting an idea. I would also urge you to consider balance and fun in your questions (and game) because getting to the final boss and then just deciding to go boom is kind of an anticlimax and leaves the other players just shrugging their shoulders and going home.

Your question reminded me of the Bomb King from FFX. :)   If you DM, you could devise a way to expend spell slots differently as a house rule, test it out and then seek feedback after play-testing.

Side-note: If I've learned anything from rewatching Dragonball stuff with my kids, it's that anytime the situation is desperate enough to consider blowing yourself up to kill the enemy, it's never enough. It fails when Chiaotzu explodes trying to stop Nappa, it fails when Vegeta explodes trying to stop Majin Buu, and (if I'm reading the wiki article correctly, haven't seen Super) it somehow fails to kill either Vegeta or Toppo when Vegeta tries it again later.

@ShadowRanger the goal in the tournament of power was not to kill the opponent, but to knock them out, and Vegeta surviving was a good thing

No such rules exist
The closest you'll get to something like this is the Retributive Strike capability of a Staff of Power or Staff of the Magi, either of which which let you break the staff over your knee to expend all remaining charges (not personal spell slots) in the staff to deal damage. In both cases, you have a 50/50 shot at surviving by traveling to another plane, otherwise, you take twice as much damage as anyone else (likely killing you unless the charge level is quite low and/or you're quite tough), and people within 30 feet of you take damage (more the closer they are).
In theory, a DM could use this capability as a model for some sort of caster-self-destruct homebrew, but it's not even remotely covered by the rules.

Wish
This is essentially the usecase for Wish's "beyond the scope" clause:

You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the DM as precisely as possible. The DM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance; the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong. This spell might simply fail, the effect you desire might only be partly achieved, or you might suffer some unforeseen consequence as a result of how you worded the wish. ...
The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way. In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days. Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast wish ever again if you suffer this stress.

This gives high-level casters an option for "Extremely powerful effects not covered by existing spells at great risk and great personal cost." Wish is notorious enough that there's an entire tag for it on this SE.
The main advice with Wish's final option is "talk to your DM", since they alone decide what happens. Wish doesn't explicitly allow you to expend all your other spell slots or say that "I will explode myself as well" should allow you to make a greater wish, but they are things that I think a reasonable DM might consider when deciding how to handle the spell.
Create a spell
The DMG has advice for working with a player to create a custom spell. This is another "talk to your DM" answer. See also: Are there rules on how to research and create new spells?
